# How many milliliters to fill cone

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, volume

A right circular cone has a depth of 103 mm and a top 
diameter of 82.4 mm. The cone contains water to a depth of 30.0 mm. How many more 
milliliters of liquid need to be added in order to fill the cone?

I understand how to find the volume, but I'm confused about the water depth. Do I just need to subtract 30 from 103 then calculate volume?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's easier to calculate the volume of two cones, that is the volume of the empty cone, and the current volume of the water, which is another cone with height given by the water depth. And you can just multiply the volume of the cone by a suitable ratio to get the volume of the water.

To find the extra water you need, just calculate the difference between the two numbers.

Answer (score 0):

HINT- ratio of (water depth) to (diameter of top of water) is constant.

When the cone is full 103/82.4 =1.25.