# How many milliliters of liquid to fill

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, trigonometry

A right circular cone has a depth of 103 mm and a top 
diameter of 82.4 mm. The cone contains water to a depth of 30.0 mm. How many more 
millilitres of liquid need to be added in order to fill the cup?

I'm not sure where to start for this question. Could someone help me please?

Comment: see [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/977768/how-many-milliliters-to-fill-cone/977872#977872)

Comment: you simply start from finding the volume

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  **Read** the question.  You have a cone.  You should have a formula for a cone (or any prism) saying $V=\frac 13 hA$, where $A$ is the area of the base and $h$ is the height.  The first sentence gives you a proportional relation between $h$ and the radius of the base, which gives you $A(h)$.  That gives you $V=(something)h^3=(something else) r^{3/2}$